# How to tell the encryption used on given string in example?

Tags: node.js, npm, lastpass

I am using an NPM package called Lastpass... it decrypts most of the info of the Lastpass vault, but not the name, notes, username and password.

Strings look like this:

```
p://sn',
notes: 'qS�\r����Xuc�\u0013��L��n����cB�a8���\u0012/�ܰ\u0000��`y�\t�^*���\tF���]��\u001b.�/�俷a擘,9{�3\u001f�0��\n�\u0012O�B�ٸ�\u001e�%2\u0006�JvP�]�\u000b>����\u0017c\rQ0$7\u0003���(�O\u000f�(�/H�~#�Q�\u0011\u001a��Y�\u0013N��?9�ٝ��ͧ{X��}XdI�k\r�����G�ƈLJ�B\u001d �\u001f�=��OM�\u00056\u000e��9�WCflX\bc�3����\u0002FR\u0017�.�B�\u0013\u0013���b1�h�#���]\u0019�\f>����Cx\u0002w��X�G\u0016�h#\u001c��C)�\u00030��V���\tG^\u001a�o���|\u0004�TC9�&�t.RBw����\u0018�ɪR%��@�
```

I can see some Unicode chars but I really dont know what encryption this is using... I hope it's nothing custom undecryptable :(

Comment: The question is off topic as it is not about coding. `notes` is not a "string", it is data, all the `�` characters are data values that do not have a character representation.

Comment: I see, @zaph is there anyway I can turn that data into something operable within nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the encryption key you will not be able to decrypt the encrypted data, it is that simple. Further the encryption key is not the password but derived from the password with a key derivation function.